# call a bash function as root but gives 'unexpected end of file'

Tags: bash, sudo, su

Why does the last example throw an error but the others work? Bash is invoked in any case.

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello {
    echo "Hello! user=$USER, uid=$UID, home=$HOME"; 
}

# Test that it works.
hello

# ok
bash -c "$(declare -f hello); hello"

# ok
sudo su $USER bash -c "$(declare -f hello); hello"

# error: bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sudo -i -u $USER bash -c "$(declare -f hello); hello"
```

Comment: Check your code in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) site

Comment: It is the same code in all examples, so it should be ok.

Comment: You have `sudo` access: just write a script and run that, instead of trying to juggle multiple levels of nesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fail because of the `-i` or `--login` switch:

It seems like when debugging with -x

```sh
$ set -x
$ sudo -i -u $USER bash -c "$(declare -f hello); hello"
++ declare -f hello
+ sudo -i -u lea bash -c 'hello () 
{ 
    echo "Hello! user=$USER, uid=$UID, home=$HOME"
}; hello'
```

Now if doing it manually it cause the same error:

```sh
sudo -i -u lea bash -c 'hello () 
{ 
    echo "Hello! user=$USER, uid=$UID, home=$HOME"
}; hello'
```

Now lets just do a simple tiny change that make it work:

```sh
sudo -i -u lea bash -c 'hello () 
{ 
    echo "Hello! user=$USER, uid=$UID, home=$HOME";}; hello'
```

The reason is that `sudo -i` runs everything like an interactive shell. And when doing so, every newline character from the `declare -f hello` is internally turned into space. The curly-brace code block need a semi-colon before the closing curly-brace when on the same line, which `declare -f funcname` does not provide since it expands the function source with closing curly brace at a new line.

Now lets make this behaviour very straightforward:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo hello 
echo world'
hello
world
```

It executes both `echo` statements because they are separated by a newline.

but:

```
$ sudo -i bash -c 'echo hello 
echo world'
hello echo world
```

It executes the first `echo` statement that prints everything as arguments because the newline has been replaced by a space.

Comment: I added `set -x` in order to see what is substituted. It is in both cases (bottom ones) the same. What do you mean by OP's error?

Comment: @Socowi I found the true reason I think now.

Comment: Thank you @LéaGris for your elaborate explanation. I could follow your examples but I am still puzzled why the output is being different. Is this a mistery of bash? The argument has not changed but the outcome is different.

Comment: @LéaGris Wow, great job tracking this down. I wouldn't have thought `sudo` itself to be the culprit. @user14825657 Even though you passed the same argument to `sudo`, the argument was altered by `sudo -i` before passing it to the shell. So you inadvertedly executed different commands for `sudo su` and `sudo -i`.

Comment: Here's an even smaller demo: `sudo -i echo $'three\nseparate\nlines'` (vs. without the `-i`).

Answer (score 1):

> It is the same code in all examples, so it should be ok.

Yes, `"$(declare -f hello); hello"` is always the same string. But it is processed differently by `sudo su` and `sudo -i` as found out by [Lea Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69415923/6770384) .

`sudo -i`  quotes its arguments before passing them to `bash`. This quoting process seems to be undocumented and very poor. To see what was actually executed, you can print the argument passed to `bash -c` inside your `~/.bash_profile/`:

**Content of `~/.bash_profile`**

```
cat <<EOF
# is executed as
$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING
# resulting in output
EOF
```

**Some examples of `sudo -i`'s terrible and inconsistent quoting**

Linebreaks are replaced by line continuations

```
$ sudo -u $USER -i echo '1
2'
# is executed as
echo 1\
2
# resulting in output
12
```

Quotes are escaped as literals

```
$ sudo -u $USER -i echo \'single\' \"double\"
# is executed as
echo \'single\' \"double\"
# resulting in output
'single' "double"
```

But `$` is not quoted

```
$ sudo -u $USER -i echo \$var
# is executed as
echo $var
# resulting in output
```

---

Some side notes:

### There might be a misunderstanding in your usage of `su`.

```
sudo su $USER bash -c "some command"
```

does *not* execute `bash -c "echo 1; echo 2"`. The `-c ...` is interpreted by `su` and passed as `-c ...` to `$USER`'s default shell. Afterwards, the remaining arguments are passed to that shell as well. The executed command is

```
defaultShellOfUSER -c "some command" bash
```

You probably wanted to write

```
sudo su -s bash -c "some command" "$USER"
```

### Interactive shells behave differently

`su` just executes the command specified by `-c`. But `sudo -i` starts a login shell, in your case that login shell seems to be bash (this is not necessarily the case, see section above).

An interactive bash session behaves different from `bash -c "..."` or `bash script.sh`. An interactive bash sources files like `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and enables history expansion, aliases, and so on. For a full list see the section [Interactive Shell Behavior](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior-1) in bash's manual.